# Use One Selector And Check Location of Where Clicked Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, removechild

My plugin will duplicate a node and append it to a specified location. It includes an option to remove the duplicated node.

Example:

```
$('#duplicateMe').duplicator( {
      copyToLocation:'#copy_to_here', 
      removeButton:'.removeDuplicateBtn'
    });
```

I'm looking for a way to create a check within my plugin to determine where the removeButton is located when it is clicked and remove an item based on that.

My three use cases would be something like this:

```
if ( defaultOptions.removeButton is the item duplicated ){ 
         ... is clicked, remove itself 
       }
if ( defaultOptions.removeButton is the child of item duplicated ){ 
         ... is clicked, remove its parent, in turn removing itself 
       }
if ( defaultOptions.removeButton is NOT the item duplicated && is NOT the child of the item duplicated ){ 
         ... is clicked, remove the last item duplicated 
       }
```

I could just create two separate removeButtons. One remove button could be outside of the duplicated node and that would remove the last duplicated node. The second remove button could be created inside of the duplicated node and could remove itself. ***However, I think it would be best to have a single defaultOptions.removeButton declared and my code check for where it is located when it was clicked.***

The removeButton currently removes the last duplicated node no matter which  has that class.  That means whichever removeButton I click, it will remove the last duplicated item. It could be the one duplicated, or it could be outside of the one duplicated. It removes the last item.

I've been racking my brain over this logic for awhile. Any ideas how I could implement this?

Here's the code at work: [duplicator.js at work in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLfsw/3/)

If you click 'duplicate the rectangle' three times, you can click any of those remove s and it will remove the last duplicated item. I want you to be able to click the remove  next to idPrefix_2 and it remove only idPrefix_2. Or if you click 'remove the last rectangle', it would remove whichever blue rectangle is left over (the last one in the line up).

Answer (score 0):

When you duplicate an item, add the class `duplicated` to the new element.

```
if ($(this).is(".duplicated")) {
    $(this).remove();
} else {
    var dup = $(this).closest(".duplicated");
    if (dup.length) {
        dup.remove();
    } else {
        // remove last duplicated item
    }
}
```

Comment: This idea appears to work. I changed it a bit to be like this:

`$('body').on('click', defaultOptions.removeButton, function(){
    if ( $( this ).parent().hasClass('duplicated') ) {    
           $(this).parent().remove();        
        }else {        $(defaultOptions.copyToLocation).children().last().remove(); 
          }
      });`

However, I'm wondering if I could do it without adding a new class to the duplicated item.

Comment: You could put all the duplicated elements in an array, and then search it to see if `$(this).parent()` is in the array. But using a class is easier.

Comment: I was actually considering that as my next option. I'll probably need to do that because I need to keep track of the counter variables that get assigned to the idPrefix. I don't want to have one duplicated, so that can really only be done using an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the click event then get the button that was clicked, then remove its parent
Make sure you add "e" in the

```
$(defaultOptions.removeButton).click(function(e){
```

---

```
var thisBtn = $(e.currentTarget);
thisBtn.parent(".theBlueSquareClass").remove();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/NLfsw/4/

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't appear to work correctly yet. The remove button on the right stopped working because the code was commented out. I'll try to fiddle with it a bit and see if I can get it to work.